# what is different between hive vs path_provider flutter

Tags: flutter

I find two option to save data as local data in phone in flutter. First one by use hive and second one by use path_provider. But I want to know what is different between those two type in save data local and what is best one to save data from api to make my app fast load data. Also which one more fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive is a local database while path_provider is only accessing your units memory.

The local database need a place to be stored and thats where path_provider is needed to access a place to save the database.

Parh_provider is more like explorer on a computer while hive is the file that you want to store on your phone/tablet.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi bro / thank you / what is best one to save data from api to make app more fast ? or we can say which one more fast in that?

Comment: You will probably need both, path_provider to keep your database at the same path to access it later on, ive been using isar(similar to hive) database for store local data and path_peovider to access the isar database. But i think that hive will do the job, but as I said, you will probably need both.